# How to find non-conventionally named accessor methods of a field, java

Tags: java, reflection, pojo

For example, we have a class:

```
public class Test {
    private User user;

    public User retrieveUserProfile() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void saveUserProfile(User user) {
        this.user = user
    }
}
```

The main criterion of accessor method in this case is `return this.user;` for getter and `this.user = argName;` for setter. As additional criteria we consider getter has return type of `user` field and is no-arg method and setter has single argument of `user` field type and has `void` return type.

Is any way to define these methods?

Comment: They are displaying it correctly: the private field didn't even have to exist, it is just an implementation detail. BTW the accessor method signatures are in full accordance with the JavaBeans convention. If they weren't, your APIs wouldn't be able to work with them.

Comment: You could probably access and mutate the field directly with reflection, but you're not going to be able to tell which methods modify which fields without *significant* effort (and probably a decompiler).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You are right, but it's not the point. We just may say that `Introspector` and `BeanUtils` solve another problem and can't be useful in this case.

Comment: It is exactly to the point given your question. Maybe you should ask a question which actually addresses your problem.